# After automating my python script in the task scheduler. Getting an error in fetching data from URL link

Tags: python, sql, windows-task-scheduler

I am writing my question clearly below here. I am trying to run my python script which I would like to automate to get our internal data from this website called 'AYS'. When I am running the python script in my jupyter notebook I see the data count in the first attached image which is = '16472'. At the same time, when I run the automated python script in task scheduler, I am getting the record count as '15369' which suppose to get '16472'.** To be clear, I am losing my today's data count of '1103' records when I run the automated script.

I am attaching the python script for your reference.

[image: Today's data count]

[image: Yesterday's data count]

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import requests
import csv, json
import  datetime
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import urllib
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pyodbc
import requests.sessions
params = 'DRIVER={SQL Server};' \
         'SERVER=production14a;' \
         'PORT=1433;' \
         'DATABASE=AAA;' \
         'UID=U**;' \
         'PWD=VCxn6WTl;' \
         'SCHEMA=PROD_PNR_USER_RWXDDL'

params = urllib.parse.quote_plus(params)

conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};' \
                     'SERVER=production14a;' \
                     'PORT=1433;' \
                     'DATABASE=AAA;' \
                     'UID=U**;' \
                     'PWD=VCxn6WTl;' \
                     'SCHEMA=PROD_PNR_USER_RWXDDL')

cursor = conn.cursor()

engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s' % params)

# Set the request parameters

# Set the request parameters
url = 'https://servicenow.ACB.com/api/now/table/incident?assignment_group=b812cf47db38bfc4583779ea8c9619db&sysparm_display_value=true&sysparm_fields=number,short_description,sys_created_on,sys_created_by,closed_at,sys_updated_by,opened_at,priority,assigned_to,assignment_group,state,u_defect,description,resolved_at,urgency,impact,close_notes'



# Eg. User name="username", Password="password" for this code sample.
user = 'u4**'
pwd = 'sag@20'


# Set proper headers
headers = {"Accept":"application/json;charset=UTF-8"}

# Deleting the table and reloading

cursor.execute("delete from [AAA].[PROD_PNR_USER_RWXDDL].[AAA_AYS_Tickets] where cast((Load_TimeStamp)As Date) = CAST(getdate() AS DATE)")

print(cursor.rowcount, 'rows deleted')

conn.commit()

# Do the HTTP request
response = requests.get(url, auth=(user, pwd), headers=headers,verify=True)

# Check for HTTP codes other than 200
if response.status_code != 200: 
    print('Status:', response.status_code, 'Headers:', response.headers, 'Error Response:', response.content)
    exit()


# Decode the XML response into a dictionary and use the data
print(response.content)
json_data = json.loads(response.text)
test=json.dumps(json_data['result'])
final=test.replace('"assigned_to": ""','"assigned_to": {"display_value": "","link": ""}')
json_data2 = json.loads(final)
print(final)

#attributes =["number"]#,short_description,sys_created_on,sys_created_by,closed_at,sys_updated_by,opened_at,priority,assigned_to,assignment_group]
#data = json.load(json_response)

data_frame=json_normalize(json_data2)

# data_frame=pd.read_json(final)

del data_frame['assigned_to.link']
del data_frame['assignment_group.link']
data_frame.insert(10, 'Load_TimeStamp', pd.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0))

print(data_frame.head())

## Deleting


## engine.query('AAA_AYS_Tickets', schema='PROD_PNR_USER_RWXDDL', index=False). filter(Load_TimeStamp == getdate).delete()

## add a column for load date

data_frame.to_sql('AAA_AYS_Tickets', engine,schema='PROD_PNR_USER_RWXDDL', if_exists='append')



##insert=''
##cursor. execute('insert into [AAA].[PROD_PNR_USER_RWXDDL].[AAA_EPS_Tickets](state)As Varchar())')
## cursor.execute("""insert into [AAA].[PROD_PNR_USER_RWXDDL].[AAA_EPS_Tickets](source)as Varchar())""")

##for p in json_data2:
          #insert+=print(p['number'],',',p['short_description'],',',p['sys_created_on'],',',p['sys_created_by'],',',p['closed_at'],',',p['sys_updated_by'],',',p['sys_created_on'],',',p['opened_at'],',',p['priority'],',',p['assigned_to']['display_value'],',',p['assignment_group']['display_value'],',',datetime.datetime.now(),',',p['state'],',',p[Tags],',',p[Defect#],end = "\n")
          # print(p['assigned_to']['display_value'])      
          ##NOT IN ORDER print(p['number'],',',p['short_description'],',',p['sys_created_on'],',',p['sys_created_by'],',',p['closed_at'],',',p['sys_updated_by'],',',p['sys_created_on'],',',p['opened_at'],',',p['priority'],',',p['assigned_to']['display_value'],',',p['assignment_group']['display_value'],',',datetime.datetime.now(),',',p['state'],',',p[Tags],',',p[Defect#],end = "\n")

  ##Try Data frame      
        # print( p['number'])
      #  print( p['short_description'])p['assignment_group']['display_value'],','
```

Comment: What SQL query do you use to get the numbers `15369` and `16472`? Also you are looking for the incidents created today and assigned to some group. Having in mind your numbers, you have quite a dynamic environment, and the numbers should change with each script execution. If you ran script several times, do you see the same numbers?

Comment: @SergeyNudnov Actually, whenever I run this script. It gives me all historical incident numbers including the incident which created today. Let's say, I ran the script today - it showing 22392 records (on Jan 6th). Yes, I got a dynamic environment. You are right. If I run the script several times, I get changes in my numbers. Because the records are getting update every time on our internal website(URL link - servicenow.ACB.com)

Comment: @SergeyNudnov I am attaching the image link for your reference. You will see the incidents opened and closed dates in the picture.            https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vqj5M.png